# 403 Error when accessing Google Secrets Manager from GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, google-iam, gcp-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use Google Secrets Manager to store database credentials for a Golang application running in GKE in Autopilot mode.

I've followed the steps recommended by Google to create the cluster, create the service account within GKE and associate it with an IAM account on Google with the correct permissions.

The steps I took for this are as follows:

Create the Cluster

```bash
gcloud config set project goproject
gcloud container clusters create-auto goproject-develop-gke --project goproject --region us-central1
```

Associate the service account with the correct roles:

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding goproject-service-account@goproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member "serviceAccount:goproject.svc.id.goog[default/goproject-sa]" \
    --role "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding goproject \
    --member "serviceAccount:goproject-service-account@goproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
```

Create the service account in GKE

```bash
kubectl create serviceaccount goproject-google-sa
```

Annotate the service account with the IAM role

```bash
kubectl annotate serviceaccount goproject-google-sa \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=goproject-service-account@goproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Apply the following deployment script (image name redacted for privacy)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goproject-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goproject-service
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goproject-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goproject-service
        image: REDACTED
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: PROJECT_SERVICE_PORT
            value: "5000"
          - name: PROJECT_DB
            value: project_db
          - name: PROJECT_ID
            value: "REDACTED"
        resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
              ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
            limits:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
              ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
      serviceAccountName: goproject-google-sa
      nodeSelector:
        iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"
```

However, when I apply the deployment and run it, I'm getting a 403 Error in the code:

```bash
rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: per-RPC creds failed due to error: compute: Received 403 `Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

The following code snippet shows how I'm trying to access the secrets using the official Google libraries:

```golang
// Get environment variables from Pod spec.
projectID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")

// Create the Secrets Manager Client
client, err := secretmanager.NewClient(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return credentials
}
defer client.Close()

// Get the Secret
req := &secretmanagerpb.AccessSecretVersionRequest{
    Name: "projects/" + projectID + "/secrets/cockroach/versions/1",
}
res, err := client.AccessSecretVersion(context.Background(), req)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return credentials
}
```

Have I missed a step somewhere? I've checked the IAM page and the permissions have been added.

Comment: Are you sure the Google Service Account has the right IAM permissions?

Comment: When I go to the IAM page in the console, these are the roles listed for that service account:

Artifact Registry Writer
Secret Manager Secret Accessor
Service Account Token Creator
Workload Identity User

Comment: Are you using an access token anywhere in your code.. and also you have given permission for only accessing the secret but the error is occurring while generating can you try by giving Secret Creator role to the sa.